# WSDL unable to import binding

Tags: xml, wsdl, asmx

I'm not able to get WSDL to work, it giving me this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin>wsdl.exe /username:NOTGIVINGU/password:THEPASSWORD /v /parsableerrors http://www.stoysnet.com/stn_mfg/link/soap.php?wsdl

WSDL: error WSDL1: Unable to import binding 'Product' from namespace 'http://www.stoysnet.com/stn_mfg/link/soap.php?wsdl'.
      Unable to import operation 'exists'.
      The datatype 'http://www.stoysnet.com/stn_mfg/link/soap.php?wsdl:IDType' is missing.
```

The WSDL is located:

http://www.stoysnet.com//stn_mfg/link/soap.php?wsdl

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

1. Whoever wrote this WSDL doesn't understand XML namespaces. It makes no sense to have a query string ("?wsdl") in an XML namespace.
2. The error message you're getting is precisely correct. `IDType` is the name of an element, not the name of a type. Yet it's being referenced in a message:

   ```
   <message name="ID">
     <part name="ID" type="tns:IDType" /> 
   </message>
   ```

In other words, this WSDL is broken, and cannot work.